# Azure Pipelines - apply Build Number into App Settings

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have a Build and Release pipelines setup for a project and I want to be able to get the Build Number that was used for the Release into the running application.

I've seen a number of explainations of how to use the Release.Artifacts.{alias}.BuildNumber variable for things like the artifact output, however I haven't been able to find how to use this to directly update the App Settings for the App Service.
I've found a few Tasks available to use in the Release process that allow changing of App Settings, but none of them supported using variables from the build process (just allow setting of static values)

I want this to be set at the App Service level so that the website and all the webjobs are able to access the variable (rather than having to update several app.config files).

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delay in updating this, however this is the Powershell based solution I arrived at and this has been working well so far.

Added this as a Powershell script within the solution and updated the Build process to copy this artifact

```
param (
    $myResourceGroup,
    $mySite,
    $mySlot,
    $buildNo
)


$webApp = Get-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup -Name $mySite -Slot $mySlot
$appSettingList = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings

$hash = @{}
ForEach ($kvp in $appSettingList) {
    $hash[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value
}

$hash['BuildNumber'] = $buildNo

Set-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup -Name $mySite -AppSettings $hash -Slot $mySlot
```

This takes the parameters provided and retreives the current App Settings from the slot and adds/updates the `BuildNumber` setting to the `$buildNo` parameter that is received.

During the Release process, I added in an Azure Powershell task to call this script and then set the "Script Argurements" field to the following

```
-myResourceGroup "WebResourceGroup" -mySite "myexamplservice" -mySlot "staging" -buildNo $(Build.BuildNumber)
```

Now I can read the "BuildNumber" app setting within my website and get the deployed build number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the AppsSettings directly against the website without using an XML transform on the `web.config`, then you would need to go down the route of applying an ARM template.

Here's how you can do that via Pipelines:

1. Grab the ARM template for your site from the portal

[image]

2. Edit the template to accept a new `buildNumber` variable, and set this in the app settings for the site e.g.

   ```
   {
     "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
     "parameters": {
       "buildNumber": {
         "type": "string"
       }
     },
     ...
     "resources": [{
       "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
       ...
       "properties": {
         "siteConfig": {
           "appSettings": [
             {
               "name": "BUILD_NUMBER",
               "value": "[parameters('buildNumber')]"
             },
             ...
           ]
         }
       }
     }]
   }
   ```
3. Setup a [Azure Resource Group Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops) task to consume your template
4. Set the `buildNumber` parameter

[image]

This should result in having a `BUILD_NUMBER` app setting in your Web App that reflects the current build in Azure Pipelines.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with using ARM Templates - however shouldn't the template have any existing App Settings that are already configured on the App Service?   I have a few that already set (some as a "Slot Setting" and some not) but these do not show up at all in the template file

Comment: @StevieW I had figured it would, turns out it doesn't, maybe for security purposes as it would need to include the raw values. However, I've shown in my answer an example of how you can set the app settings, you would just need to ensure you copy all your app settings into the template as it will overwrite, not merge.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.   I've been digging further into this and I think I've found a way to update the AppSettings via Powershell instead.   Overall Powershell seems cleaner as it will modify the existing AppSettings as required without requiring an update to the process if we need to change the variables set on the App Services via the Portal.

Comment: @StevieW yep you can certainly apply changes via PowerShell too, I _think_ it just leverages ARM on the server anyway (I could be wrong).